# kaspersky rescue cd freezes at welcome to grub when pxe boot

Tags: grub, pxe, kaspersky

So I'am following the official guide for pxe booting the kaspersky rescue cd but when I boot it is freezes at "welcome to Grub".

I want to know what Causes this Problem and How to Fix it.

This is my `Dnsmasq.Conf` file.

`pxe-service=x86PC,"Antivirus",krd/boot/grub/pxe/pxegrub`

And I only changed the file `/boot/grub/i386-pc/cfg/kav_menu.cfg` in the iso.

The System I'am Trying to Boot is a Dell optiplex 755.

How do I Fix This.

Comment: Do you see any TFTP requests in your log after grub has been loaded?